# Error Android. Activity not found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have this problem and do not know how to solve it.
thanks and greetings.

```
01-08 22:55:10.442: W/dalvikvm(814): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)

01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.prueba.db.SQLView }
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.prueba.db.SQLiteExample.onClick(SQLiteExample.java:80)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-08 22:55:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(814):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare SQLView as an activity in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

To declare an activity in the manifest, you just need to type it in the format -

```
<activity android:name=".Results" />
```

- in the manifest file's XML.

So if the activity is SQLView, it would be -

```
<activity android:name=".SQLView" />
```